# How to boot headfull (vs headless) android emulator via SSH

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, adb

Via remote viewer `VNC` I can boot android emulator on remote machine

```
emulator -avd emu1
```

but via SSH on remote machine I get error

```
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: could not connect to display  ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/opt/androidtest/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" even though it was found. ((null):0, (null))


Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
 ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
 ((null):0, (null))
```

but If I boot emulator headlessly via SSH, the emulator boots

```
emulator -avd emu1 -no-window
```

Comment: How did you do the `ssh` ? Did you use `-X` or `-Y` options ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're connecting via SSH you are in a command-line session, detached from the UI. As aa result there is no link to the display, which is the error shown here:

```
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: could not connect to display  ((null):0, (null))
```

When you're in VNC, the emulator can connect to the local display easily.

You can try X-window display remoting -

export DISPLAY=0:0

and assuming you have the display remoting allowed (xhost +) on the Window session) then the emulator window will pop up there. iptables/netfilter might block this, btw, so try with/without, and then add a specific rule (TCP 6000 if memory serves)

Note that, while this works, 'xhost +' is considered bad practice (as it allows GUI session hijacking). Also, if you're SSHing then you won't really be able to see the GUI (unless you're on another Linux, in which case DISPLAY=IP_youre_SSH_ing_from:0 and xhost + on the host you're ssh'ing from will actually get you a remote display).

Answer (score 0):

To be exact, it does not matter from where you started the session but the value the `DISPLAY` environment variable contains, which indicates the XWindows display the emulator will be using to show the window and to receive mouse and keyboard events.

Then, you can start your session from SSH or VNC and set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to point to an X server you have access to.

The client program (in this case the emulator) knows which display to connect to by inspecting the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

Additionally, as it was mentioned in some comments, `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` can be used to enable X11 forwarding. In this case, you can verify how the `DISPLAY` environment variable is automatically set to forward the display.